# How to connect dynamically created tasks in timeline using jsplumb

Tags: java, task, timeline, gantt-chart, jsplumb

Suppose we have a timeline in which on mouse click a new task is created, in such case how to connect that tasks using `jsplumb`?

Comment: that certainly can be done with jsPlumb. Please provide some code to show where you have an issue (if any) so we can help. You can use jsFiddle to create a simple scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick start on what you want, read the below blog:
http://blog.emielhollander.nl/getting-started-with-jsplumb/